# What are some examples of subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ that have infinitely many limit points but contain none of them?

Tags: real-analysis

My real analysis book mentions that subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ may have the above properties, but doesn't elaborate on it. I'm wondering, what are some examples and what's the intuition? Just for context, introductory real analysis course starting on topology.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a concrete exemple, take the sequence $x_{k} = \frac{1}{n}$ it has a limit point but doesn't contain it.

Then the following set has infinitely many limit points but doesn't contain any :

$$ E = \left\lbrace \frac{1}{n+1}+k : n\in \mathbb{N}^*, k\in \mathbb{Z} \right \rbrace$$

Comment: Does this also hold for cluster (accumulation) points? As cluster points are a type of limit point. Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 7):

For every natural number $n$, pick a sequence in $(n,n+1)$ which converges to $n$. Now consider the set whose elements are those reals which appear in any of these sequences.

Then the limit points of the set is exactly $\Bbb N$, but it contains no natural numbers.

Comment: The interesting question would be : is there such a set with an uncountable number of limit points?

Comment: No. First note that such set has to be countable; then you can prove that a countable set with uncountably many limit points will have a copy of the rationals, and in particular will be dense in itself inside some interval, so it must include many of its limit points.